# Console keeps popping up after running a code in R

Tags: r, rstudio

so, after I run a line(s) of codes in Rstudio, the console always pops up showing the script again. I have tried running `Source` and `Ctrl+Shift+S`, but the same thing still happens.

Any idea how to fix it?

Thank you for any help! Cheers!

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you are describing. All R code runs in the console. Are you not working in a script file? Are you creating an Rmarkdown document or a notebook or something? When it "pops up" are you doing something to get rid of it? Where do you want your script output to go?

Comment: My understanding of the question is that OP minimizes the console window in RStudio, and it gets de-minimized as lines of code are executed. If my understanding is correct, this is normal behaviour and there is nothing to fix.

Comment: Yeah, Phil just explained it to me, thanks for the help!